# Matching a pattern in an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, pattern-matching

I am trying to match a pattern between Items in an ArrayList. I have done it so far but there is a problem. I have made it so `*` matches any item in the ArrayList. and How I am starting the matching is by doing an indexOf of the first pattern item, But if the first item is `*` it doesn't work since It's trying to indexOf `*` which does not exist as an item.

So basically here is the code.

```
public boolean matchPattern(String... strings) {
    int indexOfItem = getList().indexOf(strings[0]);
    if (indexOfItem != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            int listIndex = indexOfItem + i;
            String s = strings[i];
            if (Objects.equals("*", s)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(getList().get(listIndex), s)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem happens on this line

```
int indexOfItem = getList().indexOf(strings[0]);
```

when `strings[0]` returns `*`

can someone tell me how I can make this work with `*` as first item? I am clueless at this point. Basically a pattern will look like this

> *, 1, 2, 3, *, 5

which will match the following successfully

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

or

> random, random, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5'

but wont match

> 0, 1, random, 3, 4, 5

or

> random, random, 0, 1, random, 3, 4, 5

PS: This is just an example I don't really want to match numbers.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense - you're passing an array of `String` what pattern are you trying to match against what? When should this return `true`?

Comment: Why are you checking the first element specially? Why not just have the loop and loop over all elements?

Comment: If your first item is an asterisk, then You should return true, since every item would match, no? If so, then:

if (strings[0].equals("asterisk")) return true;

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This should only return true when all the items have matched in a row. they can be in any position in the list but has to be in a row if they are not in a row return false

Comment: @Skaparate it only returns true when all the items match in a row not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution that works for my test cases that I have tried, If anyone knows If this code can fail in certain cases feel free to post an answer.

```
public static int findPattern(List<String> strings, String... pattern) {
    findFirstString:
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex <= strings.size() - pattern.length; startIndex++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
            String p = pattern[i];
            if (!"*".equals(p) && !strings.get(startIndex + i).equals(p)) {
                continue findFirstString;
            }
        }
        return startIndex;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I then check if a pattern is matched using `!= -1` I need the index because I am injecting some data into the index.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re pattern matching, this can be done in one line using regex!

Build a regex from the input, converting the wild card to `"[^,]+"` then test the array against it:

```
/** @return -1 if no hit, otherwise the index of the first element of the part that matches */
public int matchPattern(String... strings) {
    String head = getList().toString().replaceAll("(.*)?\\b" + String.join(", ", strings).replace("*", "[^,]+") + "\\b.*", "$1");
    return head.isEmpty() ? -1 : head.replaceAll("[^,]", "").length();
}
```

Comment: That won't work if the list item pattern doesn't start from index 0.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: I thought starting from 0 was the sensible assumption. Do both ends align then?

Comment: no, The pattern can be anywhere in the list but has to be in a row to match it. I have already resolved it with 2 loops.

Comment: I have posted my answer of what works for me, please take a look at see if it can fail in certain test cases.

Comment: @SamzSakerz see my edited answer for a much simpler solution.

Comment: Since you're using regex wouldn't this slow up the code by a lot on the first few runs? I just need to run the program once.

Comment: @samz I doubt you could measure the "slow down". It will execute in a few microseconds.

Comment: I'm trying to find patterns in over 50K files in 1 JVM run, I think I can slow down quite a bit

Comment: @SamzSakerz have you timed it? What exactly is the difference in performance? Btw there’s a good reason to use regex. You need a state engine, with back tracking, etc. with regex you get that for free. You can make anything faster by parallel execution - maybe that will be fast enough. And you won’t have to worry about bugs in your code that miss edge cases.

Comment: Ah I see, I will try to time the execution if I can and see how long it takes with regex and without regex.

Comment: Oh nvm, I am actually returning the Index of the first pattern position so this wouldn't work. I will reupdate the answer since I didn't need the index at the time

Comment: @samz consider pattern = `3,3,3,*,4` and data of `3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,3`. Can you see how much back tracking would be required to find the match? That all comes for free with regex. Regarding returning the index, that too can be done with regex.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the index? I don't know regex

Comment: @samz try that. you're on you're own now.

Comment: Just tested your code, Failed on the first execution. Here is the stacktrace https://gist.github.com/LynxKik/55ce1bb21d9416ad3167b581dc7bb207